# Issue with curly brace after printing

Tags: cases, braces, printing

The following piece of code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cases}
\renewcommand{\d}[1]{\ensuremath{\operatorname{d}\!{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{cases}
f = g+a \\
\displaystyle \int_0^1 g(t)\d t = 0.
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

using the package `cases` is not printed as it is displayed in my editor and on my computer but as follows:

[image]

I guess it is related to the pdf application used to print my file or to the printer itself.

Is there a way to prevent this problem of printing if one does not have access to the printing machine or to the application used to print?

The document is printed like this by the department of my school in charge of the printings and I don't have access to the computers easily.. My question is whether there could be a solution on my side to (try to) improve the situation.

Comment: Please insert a minimal working example.

Comment: And please inform us whether or not you load the `amsmath` package.

Comment: Done: yes, I load the package `amsmath`

Comment: I run MacTeX2020, and I am *unable* to replicate the look shown in your screenshot, whether or not the `cases` package is loaded. Please tell us which TeX distribution and which operating system you use.

Comment: I don't have access to this information easily. The document is printed like this by the department of my school in charge of the printings. My question is whether there could be a solution on my side to (try to) improve the situation.

Comment: Your code compiles for me as well. Given that Mico says the same, it seems almost certain that the problem with with your school's latex distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was related to the driver of the printing machine.